# Removing Border from WinForms UserControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have UserControl with black border inside. I want to remove the border or change its color.

[image: Image of form].

Found solution but it does not remove the border:

```
public FolderView() {
    InitializeComponent();
    base.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    this.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
}

private BorderStyle border;

public new BorderStyle BorderStyle {
    get { return border; }
    set {
        border = value;
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Control is taken from this [project](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23746/TreeView-with-Columns).

UPDATE:
I am trying to draw new border. Added these lines of code at the end of `OnPaint` method in `TreeListView` class:

```
Rectangle rect = base.ClientRectangle;
ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, rect, Color.DarkBlue, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
```

However Vertical Scrollbar is painted over my border. How to resolve this? Also tried same code in `FolderViewTree` class, but scrollbar pushes border to the left (I want to have scrollbar within the border as it was originally).

[image]

Comment: You can remove the border of an UserControl in its Designer. Isn't this what you want? The Project you linked shows a UserControl with child Controls. Remove the border of the child Controls in the Designer, too. If you want to *change the Color*, you can paint a rectangle around its bounds. Or paint the background, when possible. Or use a base container (nesting two Controls)

Comment: Is the border on the user control or on a control inside the user control?

Comment: Does [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8679342/107625) give you an idea?

Comment: Or maybe [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10428539/107625) (together with the answers).

Comment: That is the border of the TreeView, not of the UserControl.  Simply set it to None with the designer.

Comment: Solved the problem described in Update. Correct place for the code was `FolderView` class. Thanks for all replays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the border belongs to the `TreeView`.
Attached is the screenshot of the designer where you should change the border to `None`. (Currently, it's set to `FixedSingle`).

[image]